# sp_BlitzCache throws Table DML warning on temp tables

Tags: sql-server, sp-blitzcache

I have been using sp_BlitzCache to troubleshoot some performance issues on a client's SQL Server 2012 instance.  I am running:

```
EXEC sp_BlitzCache @ExpertMode=1, @SortOrder = 'reads';
```

And one of the procedures high up on the dummy board is being flagged with a "Table DML" warning.

The only thing that I can see going on is the creation, use and dropping of a temp table named #Fred.

Besides the name of the temp table ;) , should I be concerned about this warning?  Based on the details in the link https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/table-dml/ it seems like this is a false positive of sorts.  If not, what concerns are there with temp table usage such that a warning is raised?

Btw #Fred replaced @Fred due to table variable warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for using `sp_BlitzCache`!

No, don't worry about that one. It's a more general check that sometimes snags temp tables.

As an aside, make sure you're running the [most recent version](http://firstresponderkit.org), if you're not already.

You should also use the GitHub repository I linked to to file issues.

Thanks!

Comment: @JeffMergler Sure, open an issue on GitHub and I'll point you in the right direction.